# std::bind overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, std

The following code works fine

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class A
{
  int operator()( int i, int j ) { return i - j; }
};

A a;
auto aBind = bind( &A::operator(), ref(a), _2, _1 );
```

This does not

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class A
{
  int operator()( int i, int j ) { return i - j; }
  int operator()( int i ) { return -i; }
};

A a;
auto aBind = bind( &A::operator(), ref(a), _2, _1 );
```

I have tried playing around with the syntax to try and explicitly resolve which function I want in the code that does not work without luck so far.  How do I write the bind line in order to choose the call that takes the two integer arguments?

Comment: `A::operator()` does not refer to a single function but to a family of functions : I think you have to cast to it in order to 'select' the right overload. I'm not validating this as an answer as I'm unfamiliar with C++0x and I may not be aware of a more elegant solution.

Comment: I wrote [an answer to a similar question](/a/37302949), showing three ways to coerce the argument to the correct type.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need a cast to disambiguate the overloaded function:

```
(int(A::*)(int,int))&A::operator()
```

Comment: I'd write that as `static_cast<int(A::*)(int,int)>(&A::operator())`, to be explicit that it isn't a conversion

Comment: You should be able to simply assign to a temporary of the right type (`int(A::*method)(int,int) = &A::operator();`) and use that.  Personally, I have a small `up_cast()` method: `template<typename T, typename U>
T up_cast(U value)
{
    return value;
}` - that's even clearer than `static_cast` that there's no conversion going on.

Answer (score 18):

If you have C++11 available you should prefer lambdas over [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) since it usually results in code that is more readable:

```
auto aBind = [&a](int i, int j){ return a(i, j); };
```

compared to

```
auto aBind = std::bind(static_cast<int(A::*)(int,int)>(&A::operator()), std::ref(a), std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: Not only more readable, but also better performing. I remember watching a presentation about it. The conclusion was that std::bind disallows compiler from performing various optimizations, while it has no problems, when using lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

There are some "lift" macros available that automate passing overload sets as parameters by wrapping them into a lambda that simply forwards all parameters passed to it. One that is provided by Boost can make the code compile via

```
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>

auto aBind = bind(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(&A::operator()), ref(a), _2, _1 );
```

There are also proposals for making it easier to pass overload sets, see e.g. [P0834](https://wg21.link/P0834), but I don't know whether this will find or found consensus.