# std::async with overloaded functions

Tags: c++, overloading, stdasync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [std::bind overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159487/stdbind-overload-resolution)

Consider following C++ example

```
class A
{
public:
    int foo(int a, int b);
    int foo(int a, double b);
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, &A::foo, &a, 2, 3.5);
}
```

This gives 'std::async' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous. How do I resolve this ambiguity??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Help the compiler resolve ambiguity telling which overload you want:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, static_cast<int(A::*)(int,double)>(&A::foo), &a, 2, 3.5);
//                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

or use lambda expression instead:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, [&a] { return a.foo(2, 3.5); });
```

Comment: When I'm using the lambda expressionauto
`f = std::async(std::launch::async, [&a] { a.foo(2, 3.5); });
int x = f.get();` is not work. Is there any especial way of getting the value?

Comment: @AmithChinthaka `return a.foo(2, 3.5);`

Answer (score 4):

With the help of [std::bind overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159487/stdbind-overload-resolution) I figure out a solution for my question. There are two way of doing this (according to me).

1. Using `std::bind`

   ```
   std::function<int(int,double)> func = std::bind((int(A::*)(int,double))&A::foo,&a,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2);
   auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, func, 2, 3.5);
   ```
2. Directly using above function binding

   ```
   auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, (int(A::*)(int, double))&A::foo, &a, 2, 3.5)
   ```