# Why can't `std::async` pick the correct overload?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdasync

Please consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

std::size_t calc_something(std::size_t lim_)
{   
    std::size_t result = lim_ * 10;
    return result;
}

void calc_something(std::size_t lim_, std::promise<std::size_t> &promise_)
{   
    std::size_t result = lim_ * 10;
    promise_.set_value(result);
}

void async_calc()
{
    std::future<std::size_t> async_calc = std::async(calc_something, 5);
    std::cout<< "async_calc = " << async_calc.get() <<std::endl;
}
```

I am still new to multi-threading, but why -on earth- can't `std::async` pick the correct overload? The second overload uses a reference to an `std::promise` object.

I've looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033386/stdasync-with-overloaded-functions) but it doesn't explain why. Also, I do not get an ambiguity error.

The error I get is:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'async' std::future<std::size_t> async_calc = std::async(calc_something, 5);
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload resolution happens based on types of arguments specified at the call site. When you're calling `std::async`, you're not calling `calc_something` but passing a pointer to the function to `std::async`. There are no `calc_something` call arguments and no way to resolve which of the two overloads' address to pass to `std::async`.

The compiler cannot use the subsequent arguments of `std::async` to resolve the overload. From the compiler's perspective, all `std::async` arguments are unrelated and nothing implies they will be used to invoke `calc_something`. In fact, you can call `std::async` with arguments of types different from those `calc_something` accepts, and it will work because they will get converted when `calc_something` is invoked.

In order to resolve this ambiguity, you must explicitly cast the pointer to `calc_something` to the exact type of the function pointer, matching one of the overloads.

```
std::async((std::size_t (*)(std::size_t))calc_something, 5);
```

Comment: It's useful to write a simple helper template, e.g. `overload` or `overload_of` so you can write `overload<std::size_t>(calc_something)` which is a lot more self-explanatory than an explicit function pointer cast.

Comment: You will also have to specify return type in template parameters. And you would also have to make a similar helper for member functions. At this point it's not really better than a cast.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: You say that there are no `calc_something` call arguments so I understand why a function pointer itself could cause problems. However, the second argument in the `std::async` is the argument to the function. Why can't `std::async` use that to determine the correct overload???

Comment: @AndreySemashev if `overload` is a class template, with a template static member function `of`, then `overload<std::size_t>::of(&calc_something)` can deduce the return type from it's argument

Comment: It's not `std::async` who does the resolution, it's the compiler, and `std::async` is not special. From the compiler's perspective, all `std::async` arguments are unrelated and nothing implies they will be used to invoke `calc_something`. In fact, you can call `std::async` with arguments of types different from those `calc_something` accepts, and it will work because they will get converted when `calc_something` is invoked.

Comment: Aaahhh! Now THAT makes sense! Could you please add this sentence: "From the compiler's perspective, all std::async arguments are unrelated and nothing implies they will be used to invoke calc_something." in your answer so that I can accept it! Thanks! I thought `std::async` would use those args to determine the correct overload. Since they are all unrelated, then it's pretty obvious why it can't figure it out.

Comment: @Caleth I don't think I understand how.

Comment: @AndreySemashev have a look at `QOverload` https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h

Answer (score 3):

Overload sets cannot be sent as parameter as is, it must be converted to a function pointer first, or must be lifted into an object.

Overload sets must be converted since only the name of the function denote the complete set of functions, but you must send only one of those. How the compiler chooses the right one depends on the arguments you sent to it. Calling it provides the type of the parameters, but converting to a function pointer also provide the compiler with enough information about which overload must be sent.

Converting to a function pointer is usually the easy way:

```
auto function = static_cast<std::size_t(*)(std::size_t)>(calc_something);
std::future<std::size_t> async_calc = std::async(function, 5);
```

Lifting is done using a lambda:

```
std::future<std::size_t> async_calc = std::async([](auto lim) { return calc_something(lim); }, 5);
```

Lifting here is possible since you call the overload set, so there is a parameter the compiler can choose.

It just cannot delay that decision for overload sets, but for lambda and template function it can.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I needed a bit more explanation on why rather than just how to fix it, but your answer isn't wrong.

Comment: The lifting seems neater than the casting.

Answer (score 2):

`std::async()` is a *function template* and you pass `calc_something` as an argument to it. However, there are two functions called `calc_something` due to overloading. The `calc_something()` overload has to be selected before the template deduction of `std::async()`'s arguments takes place.

```
std::future<std::size_t> async_calc = std::async(calc_something, 5);
```

In the code above, which overload will be passed to `std::async()`?

```
std::size_t calc_something(std::size_t);
void calc_something(std::size_t, std::promise<std::size_t> &);
```

You have to specify:

```
std::async(static_cast<std::size_t(*)(std::size_t)>(calc_something), 5);
```

Comment: I would suspect it would use the overload with only one parameter since I only give one extra argument to `std::async` the fist one being the function pointer. Why doesn't `std::async` use these arguments to determine the correct overload?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos It can't, all your second argument (i.e., `5`) does in the call to `std::sync()` is to make the corresponding template argument to be deduced to `int`, nothing else. It doesn't participate in the deduction of the template argument corresponding to the first parameter.

Comment: Yep! Nice one. Same as the answer above, so +1. Thanks!